# Transit visa in Dammam

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, saudi-arabia, dammam

I am an Indian citizen and I have Schengen visa. I have a flight from Warsaw to Budapest  and then to Dammam and India. There is a layover of 4 hours in Dammam. Will I need any  kind of transit visa?

Comment: Is this a self-transfer? [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true) says *TWOV: Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED), Medina (MED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.*

Comment: However, if this is a self-connection, remember all the risks involved, in case of delays, schedule changes, or cancellations…